# Forcing Keras to create a different instance of custom layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, keras-2

I have written a Keras custom layer `foo` (no trainable weights within it), which accepts an input `x` and returns `x + n` where `n` is additive white Gaussian noise with a pre-specified standard deviation. I wish to train my functional model `model-trg`, which includes `foo`, instantiated with noise level set to `sigma-trg` (during training phase). In the test model `model-test`, I duplicate all trainable layers of `model-trg` except `foo`. In `model-test`, I would like to create a second different instance of `foo` with parameter `sigma-test`, different from `sigma-trg`. The objective is to test whether the model, following training, is able to generalize its learning for different noise levels.

Surprisingly, when I print the summary of `model-trg` and `model-test`, they appear to use `foo` as a shared layer i.e. the standard deviation parameter for `model-test` appears to be set identically to the standard deviation parameter in `model-trg`. The end result is that the performance of my test model is no different than the performance of my training model.

Are there any suggestions on how to force Keras during compilation to avoid creating shared layers if parameters within that layer is different across the training and test model?

Sharing layers across models

```
if enable_trg is True:
     model_trg = Model(inputs=source_input, outputs= preds)
     # some code specifying the layers and connections
     # some code to compile and train the model
     model_trg.save_weights(model_name + '.h5') # save weights

if enable_test is True: 
    model_trg.load_weights(model_name + '.h5')    
    model_test= Model(inputs=source_input, outputs = preds)
```

Training model

```
y = foo(batch_size=trg_batch_size,noise_stdev=stdev_trg)(x)
```

Test model

```
y = foo(batch_size=test_batch_size,noise_stdev=stdev_test)(x)
```

Custom layer

```
class Foo(Layer): 
    def __init__(self, batch_size, noise_stdev, **kwargs):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(**kwargs)        
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.stdev = noise_stdev                
        self.supports_masking = True

    def build(self,inputShape):
        super(Foo,self).build(inputShape)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None):                      
        y = inputs[0]
        noise = K.random_normal(shape=K.shape(y),mean=0.,stddev=self.stdev) 
        return y + noise

    def get_config(self):
        config = {
                'batch_size': self.batch_size,
                'noise_stdev': self.stdev                
                 }
        base_config = super(Foo, self).get_config()        
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```

Comment: Ok, removed comments. As the code stands you have reassigned y.. is this an example or the final code?

Comment: I don't see a problem there with 2 instances, my only guess would be how you load the test model weights. If you just use `model.save` and `model.load` it also loads the config which would be identical, but can't tell without seeing the code.

Comment: @nuric: thank you - you may have pointed me at the root cause. I am using `save_weights` and `load_weights` rather than `save` and `load`. Could that be tied to the issues I am facing?

Comment: @Attersson: my understanding is that following model compilation, the tensorflow graph should determine y by adding to `x` noise at the noise level for that model (i.e. with std deviation `sigma-trg` for training model and `sigma-test` for test model). So, the fact that I have re-assigned `y` should not matter.

Comment: Makes sense. It could have, however, kept a reference when later printing the summary or otherwise displaying. Ok though.

Comment: @Attersson: Right. I plan to go through line-by-line and compare the model summaries to figure out the underlying reason - it is most likely some bug in my code.